# OpenMP inconsistently segfaulting

Tags: parallel-computing, memory-management

I parallelized my code with openMP, and now have this bug in my code that's really odd. If it's the first time I run on a computer, it segfaults, but if I run the program again it runs fine. I've never seen anything like this and was curious if anyone has seen this before or has good resources or hints on how to fix this. It's a very simple loop that it segfaults on, and I parallelized every loop with default none. The variable declaration followed by the loop is below. I had previously posted a stripped down version of the loop for readability, but it was requested that I fill it in for the sake of more clarity :

```
 real(dp)    :: q, oneOverq, L, D, Pressure, u, v, En, rho, oneOverrho
 real(dp)    :: normal(Mesh%numDims), wL(Mesh%numFields), cd_dql(Mesh%numFields, Mesh%numEdges)
 real(dp)    :: norm_dx1(Mesh%numDims, Mesh%numDims), norm_dx2(Mesh%numDims, Mesh%numDims)
 real(dp)    :: L_dx(Mesh%numDims, Mesh%numNodes), D_dx(Mesh%numDims, Mesh%numNodes)
 real(dp)    :: p_dql(Mesh%numFields), L_dql(Mesh%numFields, Mesh%numEdges), Res(Mesh%numFields, Mesh%numTri)
 INTEGER(i4) :: i, j, k, m, nodecount, cellNum, edgeNum, Node1, Node2, node, cell, cells(3)


   !$OMP PARALLEL DO Reduction(+:L, D, cL_dql, L_dx, cD_dql, D_Dx) default(none) shared(Mesh, W, grad, gamma, dRdX, Jac_2nd) &
   !$OMP private(cellnum, edgenum, node1, node2, rho, oneoverrho, u, v, En, pressure, normal, norm_dx1, norm_dx2, p_dql, wL, cell, node, cells)
   !DIR$ IVDEP:LOOP
   do cellnum = 1, Mesh%numTri
       edgeNum = Mesh%airfoilEdges(i)
       Node1   = Mesh%edgelist(edgenum,1)
       Node2   = Mesh%edgelist(edgenum,2)
       cellNum = Mesh%edgeList(edgenum,3)
       call cell_stencil(Mesh, cellnum, cells)

       wL = W(:, cellnum)

       call linear_limited_reconstruction(cellnum, edgenum, Mesh, grad(:,:,cellNum), wL)


       rho = wL(1)
       oneOverrho = 1.0_dp/rho
       u   = wL(2)*oneOverrho
       v   = wL(3)*oneOverrho
       En  = wL(4)*oneOverrho

       call get_pressure(rho, En, u, v, pressure)

       p_dql(1) = (gamma - 1._dp)*half*( u**2 + v**2 )
       p_dql(2) = (gamma - 1._dp)*-u
       p_dql(3) = (gamma - 1._dp)*-v
       p_dql(4) = gamma-1._dp


       call norm_dx(node1, node2, Mesh, normal, norm_dx1, norm_dx2)

       L     = L + Pressure*normal(2)
       D     = D + Pressure*normal(1)


       do j = 1, 4
           if (j == 1) then 
               cell = cellnum
           else
               cell = cells(j-1)
           end if
           if (cell /= 0) then
               cL_dql(:,cell) = cL_dql(:,cell) + matmul(P_dql(:),Jac_2nd%wL_rc_dq(:,:,j,edgenum))*normal(2)
               cD_dql(:,cell) = cD_dql(:,cell) + matmul(P_dql(:),Jac_2nd%wL_rc_dq(:,:,j,edgenum))*normal(1)
           end if 
       end do

       L_dx(:, node1)   = L_dx(:, node1) + Pressure*norm_dx1(2, :)
       L_dx(:, node2)   = L_dx(:, node2) + Pressure*norm_dx2(2, :)
       D_dx(:, node1)   = D_dx(:, node1) + Pressure*norm_dx1(1, :)
       D_dx(:, node2)   = D_dx(:, node2) + Pressure*norm_dx2(1, :)

       do j = 1, 6
           node = Mesh%NodeStencil(j, cellnum)
           if (node /= 0) then
               do k = 1, Mesh%numFields 
                   L_dx(:,node) = L_dx(:,node) + P_dql(k)*dRdX%wL_rc_dx(k,:,j,edgenum)*normal(2)              
                   D_dx(:,node) = D_dx(:,node) + P_dql(k)*dRdX%wL_rc_dx(k,:,j,edgenum)*normal(1)
               end do
           end if
       end do  

   end do
   !$OMP END PARALLEL DO
```

I can put in the full code up in the code block, but for the sake of readability I thought it was best not to. If anyone has any advice I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: Often these sorts of heisenbugs happens because of an out-of-bounds memory access. Depending on the operating system's whim of where arrays get allocated into heap memory, that memory access can either segfault or run over into already allocated data, the first of which is obvious and the second of which is not. You can try compiling with `-fsanitize=address` and see what happens; there are also thread, leak, memory sanitizers, etc.

Comment: As with all things, I posted and then found the answer (I think). It looks like default none didn't properly work. I hadn't specified two indices, i and j, that I was using to assign the data to the appropriate arrays, so I guess sometimes it corrected had them as private, and other times not so. It looks like your hunch was right, and I'll definintely use that flag in the future for my memory debugging. Do you have any other suggestions as to what sanitizers to use, etc? thanks!

Comment: The address and leak sanitizers have been the most useful to me, but I code more in C/C++ than Fortran and there you have to be more careful about memory leaks. What I would **definitely** recommend is that you put your project is on github or gitlab, set up an automated test suite for it, and enable address sanitizer for the testing build. Once that's set up, it's easy to add more sanitizers later.

Comment: If default (none) is not working properly that is a VERY broken compiler - what is it? To be honest that would be so broken that I can't believe what you attest to be the problem. But to say more we really need to see at the very least "**Computational things**" and the declaration of the variables.

Comment: It's the intel ifort compiler. I used the i and j variables inside the computational section. From my understanding of default(none) it should have given an error since I hadn't specified either public or private. Since I made this change, I haven't had a problem.

Comment: If you want em two, I can put in the snippets of the computational portion with just the i and j variables.

Comment: It might help - but just as important is how the variables in scope in the parallel region are declared; are any of the reductions arrays? And you are running with all run time checks turned on, aren't you?

Comment: The reductions are mostly arrays, only L and D aren't. I ran with all checks on and it just segfaulted without any explanation. when I run without all the checks then it works as long as I run it once and have it segfault. It's the weirdest thing I had ever seen. I think that the issue was the lack of declaring i and j to be private, but that should have been flagged both by default(none) and the compiler array bound check when I ran with those checks on and tried to access the 0 element of an array starting at 1. I added the computational portion

Comment: If it is segfaulting with run time checks on that strongly suggests a bug to me. I and J should be scoped as private, yes, but I can not believe that is the issue. I would turn on the traceback options, and if necessary run it through a debugger. However just one other thought, does ulimit -s unlimited (assuming a linux) before you run it help? Related, what are the dimensions of the arrays, especially those involved in the reductions? Beyond that unless you can show us a minimal example which shows your issue I fear I can say little more

Comment: Can you include a minimum working example?

Comment: Also: try using OMP_THREAD_NUM environment variable to set threads to 1. Does the problem arise then? Also: try commenting out parts of the code into the problem goes away - if all else fails that can help you track it down.

Comment: Is the difference between private and firstprivate important to you in this context?

Comment: Are your functions reentrant (no side effects)?

Comment: I ran it in a debugger and found it segfaults on entry to the loop. so it seems as though the computational portion isn't as important. When threads are set to 1 it's fine. I also set a breakpoint before I entered the loop and then got an memory error. When I increased the OMP stacksize to 1 GB the problem went away. Maybe the problem is the reduction on all the arrays leads to a very large matrix all on the stack, rather than the heap, because the 4 reduction arrays scale with the mesh sizing and these are the only non allocated arrays in the code just about.

Comment: difference between private and firstprivate isn't important

Comment: and yea, no side effects. Everything is intent(in), intent(out), or intent(inout) with very few global variables, and those that are global are never changed after they are read in at the beginning.